# How to create activity which should not destroy if I go back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I wanted to create view like what's app call page. If I use other `fragments` or activity this page should not destroy. If I destroy activity by pressing some button then only it should call destroy function. I am not understanding how this feature is working. For this feature should I use Activity or `fragment` or something else.

Comment: Please check this link might be helpful you 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/9151209/7589424 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687602/7589424

Comment: Better to use Fragment in here check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/37653673/5792379

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle back navigation by yourself.

Override activity's method `onBackPressed()` and don't call `super.onBackPressed()` in it. In this case `Activity.finish()` won't be called and `Activity` won't be destroyed. You can start other `Fragment` or `Activity` in this callback instead if you wish, or return to the first page of the `ViewPager`(presumably) the way WhatsApp does.

Exapmle:

```
@Override
void onBackPressed() {
    // No super.onBackPressed() here!!
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't Called finish() onBackPressed method  called Intent

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(home);
}
```